# SqlServer PowerShell Core Module - Could not load type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlContext' from assembly 'System.Data, Version 4.0.0.0

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-7.3, powershell-7

I am trying to run a local development environment setup script for my solution that includes the use of the SqlServer module to make changes. It has started failing. When I use the following commands to connect to the default SQL instance:

```
Set-Location SQLSERVER:\SQL
Get-ChildItem
```

The following warning is returned:

> WARNING: Could not obtain SQL Server Service information. An attempt to connect to 'MACHINENAME' failed with the following error: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlContext' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

The module was installed with `Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Scope AllUsers -AllowClobber` and loaded with `Import-Module SqlServer`. When I run `Get-Module -ListAvailable` I see a single instance of the module versioned `21.1.18256` is loaded in `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules`.

This worked on a previous work laptop but I was issued a new laptop and it does not work here. I no longer have access to the old laptop to compare.

My environment data is:

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.3
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.3
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Is there something in a newer version of PowerShell Core that broke this, or some dependency I had installed on the old laptop unknowingly that allowed this to function? All the articles on SO that I can find related to this are for .NET Framework applications, not PowerShell Core. I've also opened a request for this [on the PowerShell GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19339).

Comment: Seems odd. Does your local machine have an instance of SQL Server installed and running? If you need to connect to an SQL Server that doesn't have an accessible SQL Browser service, or you need to authenticate with SQL Login credentials, have you tried something like `New-PsDrive -Name ExampleSql -PSProvider SqlServer -Root 'SQLSERVER:\SQL\ServerNameOrIpAddress,PortNumber\DEFAULT' -Credential (Get-Credential -UserName "sa")` followed by `Get-ChildItem "ExampleSql:\Databases"`?

Comment: You may have more than one instance of SQL Server loaded on machine.  So you connection need to have both server and instance (server\instance).  Always test you SQL using SQL Server Management Studio before trying the connection in software.   The error messages are much better with SSMS.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/2014/sql-server/install/instance-configuration?view=sql-server-2014&force_isolation=true&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2017

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Gave that a try, got the same error after providing the password for the user.

Comment: @jdweng I only have one instance of SQL Server installed on the machine, and have already tested with SSMS. The issue is specific to the PS module.

Comment: The is no different between SSMS and Powershell.  The connection string in PS as the login windows in SSMS.  1) The server\instance has to be the same. 2) SSMS login window  has two options either Windows Credentials or SQL Credentials.  If Windows than you have Integrated Security = True. If SQL the connection string has username and password.  NEVER both Integrated Security and Username/password.  If you are running in PS and admin than you have to start PS by right click on PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  If still fails check login error in log files in SSMS.  It is very simple.

Comment: Not a full answer because I have no idea what went wrong, but... for myself I solved this by manually deleting the SqlServer folder from `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` and reinstalling latest version with `Install-Module -Name SqlServer`